# jQuery Droppable not updating

Tags: jquery, ajax

G'day Stackoverflow

For a website I'm working on, drag and drop functionality must be used once an AJAX request has been returned and valid data is found. If this is the case:

```
            var allowDrop = ($json[0][0]);
            if(allowDrop === "true") {
                $editorCont.addClass("allow-drop");
            }
            else {
                $editorCont.removeClass("allow-drop");
            }
```

... which works perfectly fine.

However,

```
var $editorDropCont = $("body > div#page > div#editor.allow-drop");


        $editorDropCont.droppable({
            accept: "a.drag-button.clone-drop",
            drop: function(event,ui) {
                $clone = $(ui.helper).clone();
                $editorDropCont.append($clone);
```

only works *if* the page is *loaded* in that state with class allow-drop whereas if the AJAX request is passed again, items will still be droppable even if the div does not contain that class anymore.

The droppable event is also called for after the AJAX request in hope that it would've updated the droppable state, however it does not seem to be working.

Is there any way to make the div droppable *once* the AJAX request has been called for?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It happens because `$editorDropCont` is a set of elements (or one element) you selected with `$("body > div#page > div#editor.allow-drop")`. When you add or remove classes to this set of elements they are still droppable. You have to reinitialize droppable each time AJAX request is made.

```
$editorDropCont.droppable("destroy").droppable({...});
```

OR:

```
var allowDrop = ($json[0][0]);

if (allowDrop === "true") {
    $editorDropCont.droppable("destroy").droppable({...});
} else {
    $editorDropCont.droppable("destroy");
}
```

Comment: Can the same be done with draggable()? When I tried this on draggable() it gave an error because it had already been initialized.

Comment: @zuc0001, why and when do you want to reinitialize draggable?

Comment: I need to reinitialize draggable after every AJAX request on my page. Each AJAX request will check if allowDrop is true (as from the code above ^), and if true will add that class. This is the same case with .draggable() , and because the drag event may have already initialized from the previous AJAX request, it will not work again if the class is removed or added, for example.

Comment: @zuc0001, when you drag an item, each `droppable` checks if `accept` selector meets `draggable` element. So you don't need to reinitialize draggables - only droppables.

Comment: I've tried adding "destroy" before reinitializing the droppable(), however even though it will include the new class, it still does not allow me to drop elements into the container. It only works if it was within the HTML on page load.

Comment: After implementing your code, I received a javascript within the if () statement because it was calling for destroy when droppable had not yet been initialized.

Comment: @zuc0001, you can check if droppable was initialized or not and invoke "destroy" method depending on that. Or you can initialize droppable first and then use "disable" and "enable" methods (http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#method-disable). In other words, improvise :)

Comment: Thanks! I used enable() an disable() within the if() statement and that seems to have done the trick! Cheers.